# Transparent png overlay a SVG background as a CSS style in Wordpress

Tags: css, svg

I want to have a **transparent png** overlay a **SVG background** as a CSS style in **Wordpress**.

In the Wordpress back end there is a custom CSS section where I placed this working code.
It is just the background SVG code.

```
.club {
/** To edit this background, follow this link:
http://svgeneration.com/generate/Happy-Launch Day?
x=50&y=50&radius=50&beam1=ffffff&beam2=52c5ff&beam3=0791b3&shade=ffffff&
*/
background-color: #5EB7CD;background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
}
```

I want to overlay this background with this image http://brainclub.nl/3.0/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Lampjes.png

It is white image with transparent background so you probably wouldn't see it when you click it.

For as far as I can see the problem with combining the two is that the place where I should place the image url is occupied by the SVG code.

```
background-image:url(
```

Can anyone help me combine the two?

I will be so grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overlay a bg image as such. You can only overlay elements. You might be able to set multiple background images though by comma separating them.

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/meiaE)

Selected CSS

```
  background-image:
   url(http://brainclub.nl/3.0/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Lampjes.png),
   url('data:image/svg+xml;base64, **Code chopped**);
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/